# How can I loop through all of the subsites on the home page?

Tags: custom-masterpage, sub-site

I am developing a new master page and I would like to create a coded section to add a masonry grouping of all of the subsites associated in the site collection.

I would love any advice you might offer. thx.

Answer (score 0):

use this piece of code get all subsites inside a site collection:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetSites,"sp.js");

function GetSites()
{
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/webs",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
//Display the results to a webpart zone or any text box
            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}



</script>
```

Mark it as answer if this resolves your query. thanks!

Comment: I tried the script and believe it's taking me in the right direction...   however I keep returning a 404 error?  Any suggestions?

Comment: press f12...go to scripts tag and find the above script...put debugger point and check.. on which point you are getting 404 error..